# Displaying MY public wall using AS3 without user login

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I've been trying to get this to work for a while, but I've apparently missed something.

All I want is to have the latest 3 or so posts from my clients Facebook page to populate and animate in a screensaver that I am building using Flash (AS3).

So far, every time I try to bring anything in, it requires a complete oAuth login and account link, but it's only a one way exchange (read-only, absolutely no writing, posting or even linking, since it's a screensaver) I'm not even sure the client wants pictures or anything.

I am currently trying to use the facebook-actionscript-api, but there isn't an option for the "App Login" type of Authentication that would solve most of my problems.

I'm at wits end and about to have to tell my client it can't be done. At least they'll always have twitter...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get facebook feeds without an accesstoken (even if they are public). So I guess you need to define an app within Facebook and add login stuff to your app so users can give permission to your app for basic access.

Maybe this article offers some help: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_pt1.html